# RavenDB - No results returned when enum is property is queried

Tags: indexing, ravendb

I have the following index to keep track of the number of views of a post:

```
public class PostsByRequestsIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<PostRequest, RequestsGroupResult>
{
    public PostsByRequestsIndex()
    {
        Map = posts => 
            posts.Select(r => new  { RequestCount = 1, 
            PostIdInternal = r.PostIdInternal,
            PostStatus = LoadDocument<Post>(r.Id).Status.CurrentStatus});

        Reduce = posts => posts.GroupBy(r => r.PostIdInternal).Select(
            x =>  new PostsGroupResult { PostIdInternal = x.Key,          
           RequestCount = x.Sum(s => s.RequestCount) , 
           PostStatus = x.First().PostStatus});

    }
}

public class RequestsGroupResult
{
    public PostStatus.Status PostStatus { get; set; }
    public string PostIdInternal { get; set; }
    public int RequestCount { get; set; }
}
```

this index broke queries on documents of type Post so I added another index which indexes all Posts:

```
public class PostsIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Post>
{
    public PostsIndex()
    {
        Map = Posts => Posts.Select(r => new {
            r.Id , 
            Status_CurrentStatus = r.Status.CurrentStatus, 
            r.Title , 
            r.Comments , 
            r.Content , 
//more properties
            r.Created });
        StoreAllFields(FieldStorage.Yes); 
    }
}
```

This fixes issues with existing queries on documents of type Post.

And the following query:

```
Session.Query<RequestsGroupResult, PostsByRequestsIndex>()
           .Where(r => r.PostStatus == PostStatus.Status.Init)
           .OrderByDescending(r => r.RequestCount)
```

When inspecting the index in RavenDB studio it shows PostStatus field of the index does not contain any values even though the Post documents are all correctly storing their respective status.

How should the Post.PostStatus field be indexed to retrieve its status correctly?

Comment: Are you persisting your PostStatus enum as an integer or a string?

Comment: the value is persisted as a string

Comment: Could it have something to do with the type being uknown to the server? Is using a AbstractDynamicCompilationExtension a solution?

Comment: I have been trying to setup your configuration to replicate the problem but have been struggling to make it not work! I have made a few assumptions which might not be correct. If you remove the Where statement and debug the results does `r.PostStatus == PostStatus.Status.Init` in a watch (for the results you think it should)? Does it make any odds if you change your Where to convert both sides to strings and compare them (it shouldn't!). Does it work if your where statement uses another property instead (for instance r.RequestCount > 10)?

Comment: Removing the where condition results in all 'Status.CurrentStatus' members set to the default enum value. So the question is incorrect is saying the values are loaded properly then.
Using a stringcomparison results in the server reporting it does not know how to translate ToString in the query.
I have added another field in the index to store the status value as a string. This field remains empty when inspected with Raven Studio

Comment: OK making more sense. What happens if you change your reduce to `PostStatus = x.Select(x => x.PostStatus).FirstOrDefault()'

Comment: With the modification the results remain the same - no items returned when queried on the status field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72412/discussion-between-theduck-and-levon).